# Is this an elements of the Sobolev-Space $W^{1,2}\left(0,T,H^1(\Omega),H^1(\Omega)'\right)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

> **Definition**
>   Let $p\in \mathbb{Z}$, $a<b \in \mathbb{R}$, and $X$, $Y$ be real Hilbert spaces. We define 
>   $$ W^{1,p}(a,b,X,Y) := \left\{ \varphi \, \Big| \, \varphi \in L^p(a,b,X),\, \varphi' \in L^p(a,b,Y) \right\}.$$

I am working with the Bidomain-Model which, over a time intervall [0,T], describes the electrical behaviour of the myocardial muscle considered as $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.
This model has partial differential equations which involve the intra- and extracellular voltages, $u$ and $v$, which are functions of this type: 
$$ u=u(t,x):[0,T]\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
$$ v=v(t,x):[0,T]\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

The model-equation which describes the relationship between these two is
$$ 0 = A_iu-Cv $$
with the operators $ A_i = -div(\sigma_i\nabla \cdot)$ and $ C = div\left((\sigma_i + \sigma_e)\nabla \cdot \right)$, for my pourposes.
As most of us know, if we use a computer to simulate the model, we would get approximations $\widetilde{u}$ and $\widetilde{v}$ and thus the norm
$$ \|A_i\widetilde{u}-C\widetilde{v} \|$$
becomes relevant.
In order to analytically represent and bound this residual, I am still missing to see in which space the functions $$\text{res}(t,x):=A_i\widetilde{u}(t,x)-C\widetilde{v}(t,x) \qquad \text{and}$$
$$\dot{\text{res}},$$
its time derivative, live and which norms this spaces have.

> Is it true that
>   $$ \text{res} : [0,T] \rightarrow H^1(\Omega) \quad \text{and}$$
>   $$ \dot{\text{res}} : [0,T] \rightarrow \left[H^1(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\right]\text{?}$$
>   Does
>   $$ \text{res} \in L^{2} \left(0,T,H^1(\Omega)\right) \,\, \text{and}$$
>   $$ \dot{\text{res}} \in L^{2} \left(0,T,H^1(\Omega)'\right)\text{?} \quad$$
>   Thus  following that
>   $$ \text{res} \in W^{1,2}\left(0,T,H^1(\Omega),H^1(\Omega)'\right) \,\, \text{?}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all seems to be right except for some fine details.
$\dot{\text{res}}$ can be interpreted in two ways:
**First**, as a function
$$ \dot{\text{res}} : [0,T] \rightarrow H^1(\Omega),$$
which maps time-points to (state)functions in $ H^1(\Omega)$. Under this interpretation 
$$\dot{\text{res}} \in L^2\left(0,T,H^1(\Omega)\right).$$
**Second**, as a linear form 
$$ \dot{\text{res}} : [0,T] \rightarrow H^1(\Omega)^*,$$
which maps time-points to rate-of-change-functions over (state)functions in $ H^1(\Omega)$. This means that $\dot{\text{res}}$ is a linear form over $H^1(\Omega)$, thus
$$\dot{\text{res}} \in L^2\left(0,T,H^1(\Omega)^*\right).$$
**Forthermore** you should have in mind that thanx to the [Fréchet-Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) it holds that
$$ L^2\left(0,T,H^1(\Omega)\right) \cong L^2\left(0,T,H^1(\Omega)^*\right).$$
This spaces are isometrically isomorphic and this is what lies behind the fact, that $\dot{\text{res}}$ can be interpreted as a function and/or a linear form. 
Knowing this it is now clear that taking $\dot{\text{res}}$ as a linear form, then for the function of your interest, it holds that
$$ res := A_i \widetilde{u} - C\widetilde{v} \quad \in \quad W^{1,2}\left(0,T,H^1(\Omega),H^1(\Omega)^*\right).$$

$$ $$
$$ $$
Please also consider [this questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747681/what-is-the-norm-of-the-dual-space-h1-omega). And the comment about characterizing the norms thorough the Fourier-transform.