# Prove: $ \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_p = \sup \frac{\lvert \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} \rvert}{\lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert_q} $

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm having trouble proving the following:

> Suppose that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. Then for any $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
> $$ \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_p = \sup_{\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\lvert \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} \rvert}{\lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert_q} , \qquad \mathbf{y} \neq \mathbf{0} . $$

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903484/dual-norm-intuition) post hints at the intuition behind how a proof might work, but I have no idea how to flesh out the details.

---

Definition of $p$-norm:

> Let $1 \leq p < \infty$. For $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define
> $$ \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_p = \left( \sum_{k = 1}^n \lvert x_k \rvert^p \right)^{1/p} . $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a special case of [Hölder's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure):
$$
|x\cdot y|\leq\|x\|_p\,\|y\|_q.
$$
This gives you immediately that
$$
\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_p \geq  \sup_{\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\lvert \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} \rvert}{\lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert_q} , \qquad \mathbf{y} \neq \mathbf{0} .
$$
For the reverse inequality, note that if $a_j$ is such that $x_ja_j=|x_j|$, defining $y$ by
$$
y_j=a_j\,|x_j|^{p-1}
$$
gives us
$$
\frac{|x\cdot y|}{\|y\|_q}
=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_j |x_j|^p}{\Big(\sum_j |x_j|^{q(p-1)} \Big)^{1/q}}
=\frac{\|x\|_p^p}{\|x\|_p^{p/q}}=\|x\|_p.
$$

Comment: 1. Why is $(\sum_j \lvert x_j \rvert^{q(p-1)})^{1/q} = \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_p^{1/q}$?

Comment: 2. For the reverse inequality, why are we allowed define $\mathbf{y}$? Shouldn't we be considering *all* $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$? In fact I don't understand what the reverse inequality (equality) is for.

Comment: There was a $p$ missing on the right. And $q(p-1)=p$.